# Stop __next__ from returning None

Tags: python

I need help modifying the below class to only return interger values. Right now, I'm getting the correct answer, but my list is padded with null values. I only want to change the Prize class, not the superPrize function. I think it can happen if I replace my if statement with a while statement, but I can't sort it out.

The class takes a list, and sees if the index and value of an element is divisible by two other variables.

```
class Prizes(object):
  def __init__(self, x, y, z):
    self.x = x
    self.index = -1
    self.position = y
    self.increment = z
  def __iter__(self):
    return self
  def __next__(self):
    if self.index == len(self.x) - 1:
      raise StopIteration
    self.index = self.index + 1
    if (self.index + 1) % self.position == 0 and self.x[self.index] % self.increment == 0:
      return [self.index + 1]




def superPrize(purchases, n, d):
    return list(Prizes(purchases, n, d))
```

Comment: while True: <condition> / increment / return... something like that.

Comment: [mcve] would help a lot

Comment: `return [self.index + 1]` - is this what it should be? looks like you missing something

Comment: Yaroslav, that's exactly where I'm stuck. The correct answer is being returned for every list I send in, but it's padded with nulls, which I'm looking to remove.

Comment: Jean-Francois, my while loop returns None/null values as well.

Comment: Please show an example of how you are using this code, what the input and actual output is and what output you expect instead.

Comment: What Python version are you using? I suspect that the code behaves differently between Python 2 and 3. Please add the relevant tag to the question accordingly.

Comment: Sure is, I'm closing this one as a duplicate. I'm sorry I didn't see it, but thanks for point it out.